# How does this try finally block work?

Tags: scala

I have a function where I want do this:

```
def someThing():Int = {
 val thingy:Thing = new Thing()
 try{
  thingy.getIntThingy()
 }finally{
  thingy.cleanUp()
 }
}
```

getIntThingy() returns an Int. There are temporary tables in thingy that are created on initialization that needs to be cleaned up (side effects). Will this code work or should I refactor?

Comment: your code is unclear. You don't return `thingy`, therefore the GC deletes it after leaving the method => no clean up needed.

Comment: Looks OK to me. Does it have to be in a try-catch? If not you could just store the return value in a local variable and do the cleanup before returning the Int in the final line.

Comment: What makes you think that this code doesn't do what you want it to do? Do you have any tests? If you do, which test is failing? If you don't have tests, you can't refactor (modifying code in the absence of tests isn't refactoring, by definition).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, you need to get the value from the `try` block, but it works. For example:

```
scala> val x = try { 1 } finally { println("yay") }
yay
x: Int = 1
```